# Execute stored procedure in report

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects

My stored procedure and table capture details about which reports are run, by who, and at what time. This works fine in the Crystal Reports developer environment; The sproc gets run and details are captured.

When deployed to Business Objects the insert statements inside my stored procedure don't never fire off. They are definitely in the report, but don't create any entries in the logging table. How can I resolve this?

It's almost like Crystal Reports "scrapes" the SQL out of the stored procedure, ignores insert statements, and runs a query rather than actually running the sproc.

I do not want to use auditing that comes w/ business objects, so how can I get this working instead?

Comment: what's your proc? and where's placed in your app?

Comment: edit: got this to work by having the sproc that captures usage return a value. Then place that value on bottom of the report. Color the text the same as background so user cant see it. That seems to make Business Objects run the sproc and capture the details.

Comment: This is what I did:

1. Create a table to capture details mentioned above (what report is run by who and when)
2. Create sproc to fill the table.. and also have sproc return value of "1"
3. Add sproc in db expert in CReports
4. Drag return value into report and make text same color as backround or tiny or whatever so it is hidden
5. Now when the report runs in Business Objects, it fires the sproc successfully and captures all those good details in the table
6. And after these run for a while we get good picture of report usage

Comment: note: auditing in business objects is probably the "right" way to do this. I just didnt want to mess with setting up universes and weird stuff like that

Answer (score 0):

you can get the details that you mentioned in the aplication, you don't need to use the db expert just for this info, e.g: In your app

```
Dim p As New Report
p.ReportName = getReportName()
p.User = getUser()
p.Date = getDate() or "DateTime.Now"
p.show()
```

in your report:

```
Public ReportName As String
Public User As String
Public Date As String

"object".SetParameterValue("Parameter Field Name 1", ReportName)
"object".SetParameterValue("Parameter Field Name 2", User)
"object".SetParameterValue("Parameter Field Name 3", Date)
```

And btw, you can add these data with your proc in your app and not in the report.

Comment: I don't follow :(

but this sounds interesting

I dont have an app, it's just biz objects server displaying the reports

trying to understand your post but not getting it

Comment: oh sorry, I didn't notice that is in "Business Objects"

Comment: its OK... you showed me something else really cool... what you said made me look around Crystal Reports and find I can get current user in there. Assign to a formula field and pass that into my tracking sproc.  This is very good because bfore this, best I could get was HOST_NAME() from sql server. But what turned out to suck is that HOST_NAME for business objects reports is always the server, not user workstation name. Getting user and passing from within CR is grrrrrrrrrreat!