# Stored Procedure datasources in Business Objects server

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects

How is data retrieved via a stored procedure datasource when a report is viewed within Business Objects server? It seems retrieve data when any kind of "SELECT" statement gets executed. But other DML statements in a stored procedure, like inserting to a table, get ignored.

When an application calls a stored procedure, it runs in its entirety. But with Crystal Reports in BO Server, it seems that it like it scrapes the data retrieval code out and runs while ignoring other DML statements.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.ExampleTestBlahBlah
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT TestTable (RandomColumn) 
        SELECT 'ABC';

    SELECT 'ABC' [ReturnValue]
END
```

When this query is run in Crystal Reports while `ReturnValue` is added to the report area, the issue can be seen clearly. The procedure runs correctly in the Preview, but if deployed to a BO server the insert statement gets ignored. Why?

Comment: Linking this to [Execute stored procedure in report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45717557/execute-stored-procedure-in-report)

Comment: Thank you 4444!

Also I think I have a clue. I think it is something do to with --- CACHING!!!

Because I've found when I click "refresh" while viewing report in BusinessObjects --- the insert sprocs DO run! So I think to find my answer I need to understand caching in BO better

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this behavior was caused by "Save Data with Report" option being checked on my test report. That's all it was. Turn that off and the sprocs work as expected